# The application WebViewer (process com.example.WebViewer) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: java, android, webview

I' am getting this alert error message while running the application on Eclipse Android Emulator::

```
The application WebViewer (process com.example.WebViewer) 
has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again
```

Below is all the code in the MainActivity.java file I have. Please inform me if you require more codes.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.webviewer;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    } 


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                WebView ourBrow = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Browser);
                try{
                    ourBrow.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/");
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return ourBrow; 
            }
        }

}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.webviewer.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/Browser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions what am missing in here.

Comment: You have to show more code from your Activity and your stacktrace so we could see what exception you are getting

Comment: I don't get any other exception message, only getting what I have said above.

Comment: You have to check your Logcat log in Eclipse. You have more details about your error there.

Comment: Where is your PlaceHolderFragment being defined? Have you referenced R.id.container in any layout?

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your `WebView` inside `onCreateView()`, on your `PlaceHolderFragment`, because it is part of your fragment layout. Remove it from `onCreate()`. Like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
WebView ourBrow = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Browser);
        try{
            ourBrow.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

Comment: thanks! the error message has gone and the app has opened but it still not loading the website into the WebView. Please see the updated Content....

Comment: you must return rootView at the end of onCreateView(), not ourBrow. You have to return your fragment View.